# Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:1.10.0

Tags: jmeter

I am facing issue during execution of Jmeter script using Maven :
Maven version : 3.2.1
Jmeter version : 2.11
I also tried to run Jmeter script from Command line using "mvn Jmeter:Jmeter -DperformancethreadCount=3 but facing same error in both(command line & using Jenkins)

```
  Failed to execute goal com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:1.10.0:jmeter (default-cli) on project Jmeter_Integration: D:\svn_workspace\Jmeter_Integration\target\jmeter\results\Jmeter_Jenkins.jtl (The system cannot find the file specified) -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
    Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure



    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>Jmeter_Integration</groupId>
      <artifactId>Jmeter_Integration</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>

      <name>Jmeter_Integration</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <build>        
    <plugins>            
    <plugin>            
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>            
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>            
            <version>1.10.0</version>            
                  <configuration>                
              <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>                
              <propertiesUser>                    
                             <threadCount>${performancetest.threadCount}</threadCount>     
              </propertiesUser>                
              <propertiesJMeter>                    
                <jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts>true</jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_counts>                
              </propertiesJMeter>            
            </configuration>   
            <executions>                
              <execution>                    
                <id>jmeter-tests</id>                    
                <phase>verify</phase>                    
                <goals>                    
                  <goal>jmeter</goal>                    
                </goals>                
              </execution>            
            </executions>            
          </plugin>        
        </plugins>    
      </build>

    </project>
```

Please provide guidance or solution or let me know if i am missing any configuration.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 problems with your config:

- `mvn JMeter:JMeter` command won't work unless you have some custom plugin installed
- you have

  - `performancetest.threadCount` - in the "pom.xml"
  - `performancethreadCount` - in the command line

  and these properties names need to be the **same**.

Follow next steps to resolve your issue:

1. In [JMeter's Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) define "Number of Threads" as

   ```
   ${__P(threadCount,)}
   ```

   2. Your test structure should look as follows:

      - pom.xml
      - src
      - test

        - jmeter
        - yourtest.jmx
   3. Execute your tests as:

      mvn -Dperformancetest.threadCount=3 clean verify

   or

   ```
   mvn -Dperformancetest.threadCount=3 clean install
   ```

See [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterMavenPlugin) wiki page for general information and [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide for extra tips on Maven-driven and other options on how JMeter tests can be executed.

Comment: I have corrected my steps as define in https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui  in Option 3 :  USE APACHE MAVEN. I also remove Thread count parameter and keep it static value as of now &Run my Jmeter script using "mvn verify" or "mvn insall" command from root folder. Also run the Test.jmx script of Jmeter to check the integration with maven but facing same error.Please let me know what other corrections are require. Thanks.